# Firebase Push Notifcations does not work on Test Flight

Tags: firebase, xamarin, push-notification, testflight

I have an IOS Xamarin project that uses firebase for push notifications. The push notifications are working on a debug build. I uploaded the project to Test Flight and push notification are not receiving anymore.

I have a development certificate and a production certificate. I am using an App Store provisioning profile. I have tried revoking and making new certs. I have added `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled - Yes` to the info plist. I am receiving firebase tokens in test flight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must add as well the APNS/Certificate for Production on Firebase, it happens all the time. Check you have both of them.

Better still if you use the **P8 Key**. In this case you don't need any other certificates whatsoever. For Firebase is the best approach, comment if you need more help.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean add the APNS/Cert for production onto the Firebase console? I am currently using the APN auth key on firebase and not the certificates. Should I be using the certs instead?

Comment: I was using a p8 auth key before. I tried removing my auth key and used the dev/prod certs instead but that has not worked. I re added my p8 auth key and that is also not working.